# start after resource load three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am making a fps game using three.js. i am getting a problem with the gun model load. i have a player mesh which i use for making different players using its clone() method. i am also adding the gun model to the player mesh using add() method, when the gun loads. the problem is that when i am cloning the player mesh the gun model has not loaded and due to which the mesh doesnt have the gun added.

what i want to do is to find a way to execute the code oonly after the models and other resources have loaded. is there a way to hold the whole execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you would like to use onProgress function in loading manager https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager.

Answer (score 0):

The loader.load functions all have a function parameter that is called when the load is finished:

`loader.load((thing)=>{
    //Here your thing is loaded...
     scene.add(thing);
    //start using the thing here..
    });`

Comment: is there a way any other way?